# Django Email Incorrect Accent Characters

Tags: django, email, encoding, celery

I'm facing an issue with sending emails using Django where the accent characters are not rendered correctly.
**
Problem:**

When I send an email containing accent characters (e.g., é, à, ü), they **SOMETIMES** appear  incorrectly in the received email. Instead of the correct character, I see a different symbol/letter.

I'm using Django, in particular Celery do send the emails.

Here is my code:
Template:

```
{% extends 'general/mail_header_and_footer.html' %}
{% load settings %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}
{% block description %}

    <p>Ciao {{ customer_name }},</p>

    <p>
        The booking for {{ experience_variant_name }} is not available for {{ starting_time|time:'H:i' }} of
        {% language 'it' %}
            {{ starting_date|date:'l, d F Y' }}
        {% endlanguage %}.
    </p>
```

Python:

```
email = EmailMessage(
        subject=subject,
        body=message,
        from_email=DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
        to=[booking.customer_email],
        bcc=MANAGERS_EMAILS,
        headers={"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"},
    )
    email.content_subtype = "html"
    email.send()
```

settings.py:

```
EMAIL_CHARSET = "utf-8"
```

And I'm using sendgrid.

Comment: Try adding this in your general html file and see if it works. `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> `